# Autohotkey and Cisco Jabber - Click to call

Tags: clipboard, autohotkey

I followed this Tutorial (http://www.employees.org/~dhenwood/ClicktoCall.pdf[1](http://www.employees.org/~dhenwood/ClicktoCall.pdf))) to call a marked number (in a browser, in outlook, etc). Telephone numbers as links works fine, but when I mark numbers, it does not work. Here is the code:

```
$^D::clipboard = Send ^c
ClipWait, 
clipboard = %clipboard%
StringReplace, tel, clipboard, %A_SPACE%, , All
tel := RegExReplace(tel, "\(.*\)", "")
Run, tel:%tel%
Return
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it just make a copy of the text after "clipboard =" on the first line. In this example "Send ^c".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
~$^D::
Send {ctrl down}{c down}{ctrl up}{c up}
ClipWait, 
clipboard = %clipboard%
StringReplace, tel, clipboard, %A_SPACE%, , All
tel := RegExReplace(tel, "\(.*\)", "")
Run, tel:%tel%
Return
```

Comment: weird.. just removed cliboard in the first line an it works. thank you :D